# Probability to shoot a target given number of times

Tags: probability

Suppose that there are two shooters $A$ and $B$ shooting at the target. Probability that $A$ will shoot at the target is $2/3$ and for $B$ it is $3/4$. They shoot at target $6$ times, but before the shot they flip a coin -- when the outcome is heads then $A$ shoots and when the outcome is tails then $B$ shoots. I need to compute $a)$ the probability that the target was shot $4$ times and $b)$ only $A$ shot if the target was shot $4$ times.

**For $a)$**
Let's denote by $C$ the event that the target was shot $4$ times. Obviously, if $A$ shot the target $i, i \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ times, then $B$ shot the target $4-i$ times. So
$$
\mathbb{P}(C) = 0.5\sum\limits_{i=0}^4 {6 \choose i}\cdot\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^i\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{6-i}{6 \choose 4-i}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{4-i}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{6-(4-i)} = 0.0031673
$$
However the probability is so small that I highly doubt that my reasoning is correct. I think there are simply too many terms depending on $i$, as I have a total of $12$ shoots, so twice as much.

**For $b)$** Let's denote by $D$ the event that only $A$ shoots. So
$$
\mathbb{P}(D \mid C) = \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(D \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(C)} 
$$
$\mathbb{P}(C)$ is computed above. Now
$$
\mathbb{P}(D \cap C) = 0.5\sum\limits_{i=0}^4 {6 \choose i}\cdot\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^i\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{6-i}
$$
Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

**For part (a)**

Let $~f(i)~$ denote the probability that in $~6~$ coin flips, that A wins $~i~$ of the coin flips, with $~i \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,6\}.~$  Note that when A wins $~i~$ coin flips, B wins $~(6 - i)~$ coin flips.

For $~i \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,6\},~$ and for $~j \in \{0,1,\cdots, 6\},~$ let $~g(i,j)~$ denote the probability that A hit the target exactly $~j~$ times, in $~i~$ attempts.

Assume that when $~j > i,~$ that $g(i,j) = 0.$

Similarly, for $~i \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,6\},~$ and for $~j \in \{0,1,\cdots, 6\},~$ let $~h(i,j)~$ denote the probability that B hit the target exactly $~j~$ times, in $~i~$ attempts.

Assume that when $~j > i,~$ that $h(i,j) = 0.$

Then, the final computation will be

$$\sum_{i=0}^6 \left\{ ~f(i) \times \left[ ~\sum_{j=0}^4 g(i,j) \times h(6-i,4-j) ~\right] ~\right\}. \tag1 $$

(1) above is explained as follows:

- A will shoot $~i~$ times, where $~i~$ is some element in $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,6\}.~$  When this happens, B will shoot $~(6-i)~$ times.
- When A shoots $~i~$ times, he will hit the target $~j~$ times, where $~j~$ is some element in $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,4\}.~$
- When A hits the target $~j~$ times, B will hit the target $~(4-j)~$ times in B's $~(6-i)~$ attempts.

So, part (a) is reduced to computing $~f(i), ~g(i,j),~$ and $~h(i,j).$

$$f(i) = \frac{\binom{6}{i}}{2^6}.$$

$$g(i,j) = \binom{i}{j} (2/3)^j (1/3)^{i-j} ~: ~j \leq i.$$

Similarly,

$$h(i,j) = \binom{i}{j} (3/4)^j (1/4)^{i-j} ~: ~j \leq i.$$

---

**For part (b)**

Let $~M~$ denote the probability computed in part (a).

Then, by [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), the computation for part (b) is

$$\frac{f(6) \times g(6,4)}{M}. \tag2 $$

(2) above is explained as follows.

Let $~R~$ denote the intersection of events that A took all $~6~$ shots, and hit the target $~4~$ times.

Let $~S~$ denote the union of events that A and B combined to hit the target $~4~$ times.

Then, the desired computation is

$$p(R|S) = \frac{p(R \cap S)}{p(S)}.$$

$p(S)~$ has already been calculated in part (a).

By definition, $~p(R \cap S) = p(R) = f(6) \times g(6,4).$

---

**For part (b) : Alternate Interpretation**

As indicated by the comment of nicola, immediately following my answer, there is a (viable) alternative interpretation of part (b): It is possible that B either took $~0, ~1, ~$ or $~2~$ shots, with each shot missing.  With such an interpretation, the computation for part (b) becomes:

$$\frac{1}{M} \times ~\left\{  
 ~\sum_{i=4}^6 \left[ ~f(i) \times g(i,4) \times h(6-i,0) ~\right] ~\right\}. $$

Comment: There is some ambiguity in the OP due to the "shot" term which is used both for "attempt" and "hit". The b) part might be also interpreted as: there were 4 hits on target and they all came from A. This interpretation changes your calculation, since it's possible that A, for instance, won just 4 or 5 attempts, hitting 4 of them, with B always missing.

Comment: @nicola Nice catch.  I agree that your alternative interpretation is viable.  I have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: I think that for the first part you can simplify a bit by defining the probability of hitting as $P_h = \frac{1}{2}P_B + \frac{1}{2}P_A$ and then exploit binomial distribution, since each shot is independent from each other. The answer would be $Binom(4, 6, P_h)$, where $Binom$ is the binomial mass function.

Comment: @nicola If your alternative vision for part (a) had occurred to me, then I would probably have gone down that road.  However, since it didn't, and since the approach that I took makes sense to me and is accurate, I am content to leave part (a) alone.  On the other hand, it seems to me that your part (a) approach is valuable.  So, I invite you to post a separate answer where you carefully document your part (a) approach.

Answer (score 1):

Indicator variables are your friend and they can help you here.

For each $1\leq i \leq 6$ let $X_i=1$ if the target is shot on the $i^{\text{th}}$ attempt and $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then

$$\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_i=1|A \text{ shoots})\mathbb{P}(A \text{ shoots})+\mathbb{P}(X_i=1|B \text{ shoots})\mathbb{P}(B \text{ shoots})=\frac{17}{24}$$ Hence $X=X_1 + \dots + X_6 \sim \text{Binomial}(6,\frac{17}{24})$ and so $$\mathbb{P}(X=4)={6 \choose 4}(17/24)^4(1-17/24)^2\approx 0.32$$

For (b) we use Bayes' Theorem:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}(A \text{ only shoots}|X=4) &=& \frac{\mathbb{P}(X=4|A \text{ only shoots})\mathbb{P}(A \text{ only shoots})}{\mathbb{P}(X=4)} 
 \\&=& \frac{{6 \choose 4}(2/3)^4(1-2/3)^2\times (1/2)^6}{{6 \choose 4}(17/24)^4(1-17/24)^2} \\ &\approx &  0.016 \end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 0):

In how many ways can the target be shot 4 times = $^6C_4 = 15$

How many of variations with respect to A and B can these 15 shots be made = $2^4 = 16$

There are $15 \times 16 = 240$ different ways of the target getting shot by A and B.

All A: $1$ variation, $P(E1) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4$
All B: $1$ variation, $P(E2) =\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^4$
2B2A: $^4C_2 = 6$ variations, $P(E3) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 \times \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2$
3A1B: $^4C_3 = 4$ variations, $P(E4) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 \times \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2$
1A3B: $^4C_3 = 4$ variations, $P(E5) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \times \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3$

Probability of 2A2B = $P(E6) = P(E3) \times \left(\frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} + 2 \times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{4}\right)$

Probability of 3A1B = $P(E7) = P(E4) \times \left(\frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} + 2 \times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{4}\right)$

Probability of 3B1A = $P(E8) = P(E5) \times \left(\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} + 2 \times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{4}\right)$

Probability of hitting the target exactly 4 times = $P(E9) = P(E1) + P(E2) + P(E6) + P(E7) + P(E8)$

---

The probability that A made the shots, given that the target was shot 4 times = $P(A|F) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4 \div P(E9)$